# Notifying user's browser of change without websockets

Tags: python, web, pyramid

I'm developing intranet web app that is based on Pyramid with SQLAlchemy.

It eventually may (will) happen that 2 users will edit the same record. How can I handle the requirement to notify the user who started editing later that particular record is being edited by the first user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using Server Sent Events (SSE) instead of websockets.  Pyramid itself can answer such requests without a thread constantly being consumed.  SSE is supported by most browsers except IE, and there are probably shims for IE that allow it to work.

Here's a Pyramid view that implements an SSE event stream:

https://github.com/Pylons/substanced/blob/master/substanced/audit/views.py#L49

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with current editor, record_id and timeout. The first editor asks per POST-request to edit a record and you put a new line in this table, with a reasonable timeout, say 5 min. The first editor gets an "ok" in return. For the second editor you find a match for the record_id in the table, look at the timeout, and if it's not timed out, (s)he gets an "error" in return to the post request. In an second POST-request, an editor send it's changes. You look in the table, if (s)he's the editor and send "changed" or "rejected" accordingly.